# Filter outer query by inner column value

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I've inherited some code which calls this SQL example and the task is to add a date filter.

The issue is the date property is on the inner table (table2) -  (select top 1....) etc
So I could filter the table 2 sub queries but table1 would be unaffected and I'd still get all of those records.

I've tried joining back on to table2 but get too many records back. I'm sure there is an easy and elegant solution, SQL isn't my forte as you can tell!

```
select col1,col2,col3,col4
(select top 1[col1] from[dbo].[TABLE2] where[dbo].[TABLE2].FK = [TABLE1].PK 
order by[dbo].[TABLE2].PK desc), 
(select top 1[col2] from[dbo].[TABLE2] where[dbo].[TABLE2].FK = [TABLE1].PK 
order by[dbo].[TABLE2].PK desc),
from TABLE1 where(.....)
```

Comment: Sample data and desired results would really help.  For instance, is one of those columns supposed to store dates?

Comment: Your task doesn't make much sense.    What would this date filter be expected to accomplish?

Comment: Basically the query returns a list of items (table1) that contain sub query selects from an inspection table (table2) the request is to filter by inspection date but this doesn't exist on the item table

Comment: If you had an example of the tables create and some example data you would have a clear answer.  It's not completely obvious what your generic SQL is trying to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps you want :

```
select t1.*, t2.*
from TABLE1 t1 outer apply --- Your current query suggests outer apply
     (select top (1) t2.col1, t2.col2
      from [dbo].[TABLE2] t2
      where t2.fk = t1.pk
      order by t2.pk desc
     ) t2
where(.....);
```

Comment: great @Yogesh Sharma - this was exactly what I needed, thanks!